# Segmentation Fault for separating a string from user input than putting it to a array

Tags: arrays, c, string, segmentation-fault, strtok

I'm trying to get from user input a string with spaces for example `"abcd12314 asdfg92743 ppoqws21321"` and separate them and then store them in an array. But it gives me a segmentation fault

```
int main() {
    char string[150];
    int i = 0;
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
    char *words = strtok(string, " ");
    char *stored[150];

    while (words != NULL) {
        stored[i++] = words;
        words = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        printf("%s\n", stored[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your for-loop uses `i < strlen(string);` which is the number of characters in `string`, not the number of strings in `stored`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this:

```
int main() {
    char string[150];
    int i = 0;
    fgets(string,sizeof(string),stdin);
    char *words = strtok (string, " ");
    char *stored[150];

    while (words != NULL) {
        stored[i++] = words;
        words = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    int nbofwords = i;                 // <<<< add this
    for (i = 0; i < nbofwords; i++) {  // change this line
        printf("%s\n", stored[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this code is error prone, you should rather write it like below. You should declare variables upon first usage and declare loop counters directly in the `for` statement.

```
int main() {
  char string[150];
  fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);

  char* stored[150];
  int nbofwords = 0;
  
  char* words = strtok(string, " ");
  while (words != NULL) {
    stored[nbofwords++] = words;
    words = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < nbofwords; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", stored[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: this is untested code.